# Hive tables not visible in Spark 2.1.1

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I created a database and a table and loaded data in it from the Hive terminal. However, when I am trying to access the table from Spark, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: employee;
```

As mentioned in some other SO answers, I have already placed my hive-site.xml in the spark/conf directory.

The following is the code that I additionally put in the hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hive/iotmp</value>
  <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hive/iotmp</value>
  <description>Location of Hive run time structured log file</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hive/iotmp</value>
  <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true </value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
</property>
```

The following is my Java code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
public class SparkHiveExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark session example")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();
    System.out.println("show tables ---> "+session.sql("select * from employee").count());

 }
}
```

I am using the following command to run:

```
spark-submit --class SparkHiveExample --master local[4] /Users/akanchan/Documents/workspace/testone/target/simple-project-1.0.jar
```

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Are you literally executing `select * from employee`?  If so, maybe you need to qualify the table with the db name?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got it working by running the spark-submit command from within the $HIVE_HOME directory. Do you know of a way to avoid this?

Comment: Note that these Hive dependencies must also be present on all of the worker nodes, as they will need access to the Hive serialization and deserialization libraries (SerDes) in order to access data stored in Hive.Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml, core-site.xml (for security configuration), and hdfs-site.xml (for HDFS configuration) file in conf/. for more reference please refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables